# Read Image Message from in ROS MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, ros, subscribe

Please, does any one know how to read an image message from ROS into Matlab?
I already receive the message and get a org.jboss.netty.buffer.SlicedChannelBuffer object after calling message.getData().

However I have no idea how to extract data and put it inside a uint8 vector.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Pedro

Answer (score 1):

Found it!
Just use the .array that comes with the org.jboss.netty.buffer.SlicedChannelBuffer object.
That is, for a 640x640 image:

```
a = message.getData();
data = a.array;
I = typecast(data(a.arrayOffset+1:end), 'uint8');
I = cat(3, reshape(I(3:3:end),[640 640])', ...
    reshape(I(2:3:end),[640 640])', ...
    reshape(I(1:3:end),[640 640])'...
);
```

remember to cat to uint8 because array gives you a int8 data type.

See ya